# How can I develop azure function app which originally created on the portal but would like to continuously develop locally

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-function-app

I created a function app from the portal. However, I would like to continuously develop the same function app locally with VS code.

I downloaded a content file from overview page clicking "Download app content".
[image]

After I finish developing locally, I would like to push back to the portal without creating new function app. Is there a way to achieve this...? Maybe tweak function app extension and repoint the the Files folder to local folder?

[image]

Appreciate any suggestion or tip in advance.
Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way for you to be able to view and make changes to your code via the portal if you do local development.

From the Microsoft Docs :

> The Azure portal features a functions editor experience, but in most
> cases it does not support working with functions that were developed
> locally. Once you start using a local development workflow based on
> the Core Tools, don't expect to be able to use the portal to make
> changes to your functions.

Link to doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/develop-test-deploy-azure-functions-with-core-tools/2-create-run-functions-locally-core-tools